# Facebook App Review policies

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I read that I need to demonstrate the way to connect to Facebook and the permissions that I want to use.

But my question is, my app uses the Graph API to pull the reviews data of all the pages that belong to my app in Facebook, but this process is made by connection through a service without visual interface.

Is there a way to submit this process because I can not have visual evidences?

Best regards

Comment: How are you using the review data?

Comment: by analytic way... we pulled those reviews using graph API Facebook with an internal service. We save all these results in our database, then in a Portal we show to the owners a result of those reviews and the impact of them